# Get product position from category

Tags: product, magento-1, navigation

I'm implementing Prev/Next button on Product view page following [Inchoo's Blog](http://inchoo.net/magento/simple-helper-class-for-previous-next-products-in-magento/). It's working fine with Default Magento Theme but in My theme there is an issue with getting product position from Category.

In Product's view.phtml I've added code

```
<?php $_prev = $this->helper('retailon_productprevnext')->getPreviousProduct(); ?>
<?php $_next = $this->helper('retailon_productprevnext')->getNextProduct(); ?>
<?php if($_prev): ?><a class="product-prev" href="<?php echo $_prev;?>"><?php echo $this->__('< Previous')?></a><?php endif; ?>
<?php if($_next): ?><a class="product-next" href="<?php echo $_next;?>"><?php echo $this->__('Next >')?></a><?php endif; ?>
```

The Code for previous product in my Helper is like this:

```
     public function getPreviousProduct()
        {
            $prodId = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();

            $catArray = Mage::registry('current_category');

            if($catArray){
var_dump($catArray); 
                $catArray = $catArray->getProductsPosition();

var_dump($catArray); 
/// Remaining code to return previous product
```

First dump is returning category array info, while the second one is not dumping any value.

Is there any other way using which I can get product position from category array instead of using   `$catArray = $catArray->getProductsPosition();` ?

Answer (score 1):

If the first dump returns an array, I would be astonished if the second dump actually gets executed.

```
$catArray = $catArray->getProductsPosition();
```

...must give you a fatal error, because you are calling a function on a non-object.
My guess: the products position data is not loaded in the current-category-registry. So what I'd try is:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catArray['entity_id']);
$positions = $category->getProductsPosition();
Zend_Debug::dump($positions);
```

Comment: I think he may be miss-interpreting the var_dump of the  OBJECT as an array, due to how var_dump is outputting the result.